# Set value of button based on returned value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a `GridView` in asp.net.

The first column is a list of button controls -

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="statusButton" runat="server" Text="Select" 
            OnClick="statusButton_CheckedChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

However I want to modify the background color and Text values of this button on data bind based on the value of another column in the table.

My problem being I need to check the values of the other column as they are retrieved, they will either be `1` or `-1` and that value will set the design of the button.

How can I check the values of this bound field -

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="EXCLUDE" HeaderText="EXCLUDE" SortExpression="EXCLUDE" 
     ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass = "hideGridColumn" 
     ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn"/>
```

To then set the colour and text of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RowDataBound` event of the gridview, for example:

```
    myGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(myGrid_RowDataBound);
    void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                //Raised after each row is databound
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    string value = e.Row.Cells[5].Text; //sixth column
                    if (value == "1")
                    {
                        //change button color (assuming button is in first column)
                        Button myButton = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Button;
                        myButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: This can retrieve the values! However the button gets this error -Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. An explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast? How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Jambo: try e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Button; I updated my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Change it as follows

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="statusButton" runat="server" Text="Select" 
        OnClick="statusButton_CheckedChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

use different css-classes according to your condition

```
.class1{
 color:red;
 font-size:10;
}
.class2{
 color:blue;
 font-size:12;
}

<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="statusButton" runat="server" Text="Select" 
        CssClass='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("EXCLUDE"))== "1" ? "class1" : "class2" %>' 
        OnClick="statusButton_CheckedChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can use it from the C# on `RowDataBound` event as suggested by @edwin

Comment: Good advice with the CSS class however I needed slightly more control over handling the values in the code behind.